# How to apply group policy and regedit policy in Ubuntu 11.10? 

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, group-policy

I have a Windows server and all the clients are linux based(Ubuntu 11.10),I want to set up group/domain policy on my network. Please suggest anything other than likewise-open policy.
Or how to apply group policy in local machine.

Comment: A quick googling turned this up, not sure if it'll be useful as it seems like it is pretty limited. [PowerBroker Identity Services](http://www.beyondtrust.com/Products/PowerBroker-Identity-Services/In-Depth-Features/Integration/Group-Policy/) . It doesn't seem like this is a common thing to try to do.

Comment: "Windows server, Linux clients" - usually it's the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

We've had pretty good luck with our limited trials of [Centrify's DirectControl](http://www.centrify.com/directcontrol/grouppolicy.asp) product:

> Centrify DirectControl delivers the industry's most comprehensive
>   support for extending Group Policy to non-Windows systems. It is the
>   only solution to provide both user and computer policies, Mac-specific
>   desktop lockdown policies, and advanced features such as group
>   filtering and loopback processing. Group Policy functionality is
>   seamlessly integrated into the all-in-one DirectControl Agent; there's
>   nothing else to buy, nothing else to install. DirectControl is the
>   only solution that provides authentication, access control, and Group
>   Policy for non-Microsoft systems as a single, seamlessly integrated
>   agent.